# Python tic tac toe

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a tic tac toe game following Clever Programmer guide on youtube. Everything goes well as it does on tutorial until that moment:

```
board = ['-','-','-',
         '-','-','-',
         '-','-','-',]

def display_board():
    print(board[0] + ' | ' + board[1]  + ' | ' +board[2])    
    print(board[3] + ' | ' + board[4]  + ' | ' +board[5])  
    print(board[6] + ' | ' + board[7]  + ' | ' +board[8])  


def play_game():
    # Display initial board
    display_board()


    handle_turn()


def handle_turn():
    position = input("Choose a position from 1-9: ")
    postion = int(position) - 1

    board[position] =  "X"
    display_board()



play_game()
```

Yeah so basically when he runs it, he can choose a number from 1 to 9 and one of the minuses on board changes to "X". 
When I do that I get a problem and the console says

`"TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str".`

Can you help me? I don't know if it's important because I'm really a newbie but he uses python 3.6.1 and I'm using 3.7

Comment: Please provide the complete error message (including line number).

Comment: postion  => position

Comment: It's just a typo! "postion" should be "position" in "hande_turn()"

Comment: Highlighted the exception message with spelling and grammar corrections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a **typo** in the code snippet you have posted. Below is the line where the variable position is misspelt.

**Incorrect line of code**

```
postion = int(position) - 1
```

**Corrected code snippet**

```
board = ['-','-','-',
         '-','-','-',
         '-','-','-',]

def display_board():
    print(board[0] + ' | ' + board[1]  + ' | ' +board[2])
    print(board[3] + ' | ' + board[4]  + ' | ' +board[5])
    print(board[6] + ' | ' + board[7]  + ' | ' +board[8])

def handle_turn():
    position = input("Choose a position from 1-9: ")
    position = int(position) - 1

    board[position] =  "X"
    display_board()

def play_game():
    # Display initial board
    display_board()
    handle_turn()

play_game()
```

This code would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typoo in handle_turn. Change it to:

```
def handle_turn():
    position = input("Choose a position from 1-9: ")
    position = int(position) - 1

    board[position] =  "X"
    display_board()
```